# Activity methods: protected onDestroy(), but public onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android

I have just a curiosity. 
If I override `onBackPressed()`, `onDestroy()` I notice that:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed()

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
```

Why `onBackPressed()` is `public` and `onDestroy()` is `protected`?

I know the difference between `protected` and `public` but I don't understand why they have different modifiers. It is just a curiosity.